# What is meant by ethereum becoming 'deflationary'?

Tags: ether

I have read that the transition to proof of stake will result in Ethereum becoming deflationary.

What does becoming deflationary mean in the context of Ethereum? Is this a statement about the percentage change of Ethereum tokens created, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means that the amount of ETH that is being burned due to [EIP-1559](https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/eip-1559-faq) will exceed the issuance of ETH from [staking rewards](https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-roadmap/ethereum-2.0/eth-2.0-economics/) . However, there is no way of knowing if this will actually be the case until the merge occurs, and will be dependent on many factors such as validators going offline, being slashed, and the change in transaction volume after the merge.

Comment: How does transaction volume come into the equation?

Comment: Sorry that it was unclear. I meant transaction volume in the sense that more transactions will generally lead to more ETH burning from EIP-1559 and thus greater deflationary pressure.